# Why is my CSS getting overridden?

Tags: jquery, css, html

MY CSS is called ppcss.css but after the 3 jquery links that i have, it overrides my css and makes my page look different. Can anyone help me solve this issue? modify or change code for explaining me. thank you.

```js
    $(function() {

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    });
```

```css
body { background-color:#00BFFF;}
  
    div#header { width:auto;
   height:75px;
   background-image:url('banner.gif');
    } 
    h1{ color:white;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:1.8em;
   
   }
    h3{ color:white;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:1em;
   
   }
  
    div#wrapper{width:1200px;
   background-color:#fff;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   
   
   } 
    
    h1.head,h3.subhead{font-family:georgia,serif;
     margin-left;20px;}
      
    
       
    h1.head{font-size;2.25em;
  padding-top:15px;
  
    }
    h3.subhead{ margin-top:-20px;
   letter-spacing:1px;
    }
    ul#navlist li{ display:inline;
   list-style-type:none;
   padding-right:30px;}
    ul#navlist{   
   background-color:#ADFF2F;
   margin-top:.99px;
   margin-bottom:1.99px;
   }
    ul#navlist a{   
   text-decoration:none;
   font-size:1.5em;
   }  
     ul#navlist a:hover{ color:red;  
     
   } 
 
    div#leftcol{ float:left;
   width:180px;
   margin-left:2px;}


    div#maincol{float:left;
     width:500px;
   margin-left:15px;
   margin-right:15px;
   text-align:center;
   }
    div#maincol h5{font-size:85%;
   line-height:1.25em;
   text-align:center;
   margin-right:1px;
   font-family:arial, sans-serif;
   }
   
    div#rightcol{ width:180px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20epx;
    
    }
    div#footer{ background-color:#ADFF2F;
     height:15px;
     clear:both;}
    #home div.smfeature{width:180px;
   height:auto;
   border:thin solid red;
   margin-bottom:10px;}
    #home div.smfeature h4 { font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:75%;
    color:brown;
    background:#48D1CC;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    padding:.5em;
    
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    }
    div#searchbox2 { background-color:#7B68EE;
     text-align:center;
     }
    div#links { width:150px;
   height:auto;
   text-align:center;
   }
    a { text-decoration: none;
 }    
    p a:hover{ color:red;}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Homepage</a></li>

    <li><a href="animals.html">Animals</a></li>

    <li><a href="Algae.html">Plants</a></li>

    <li><a href="FAQS.html">F.A.Qs</a></li>
 
 <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="home">
 <div id="wrapper">
 <!-- header -->
 <div id="header">
 <h1 class="head"> Underwater World </h1>
 <h3 class="subhead">
 A New World!
 </h3>
 </div>
 
  
 <!-- left column -->
 <div id="leftcol" >
 
 <div class="smfeature">
 <h4> Who we are. </h4>
 
 </div>
 
 <div class="smfeature">
```

Comment: Try to add a fiddle, it will encourage people to answer your question.

Comment: @PrashantKumar how do i add a fiddle?

Comment: Use this link  http://jsfiddle.net/  and add your code ..

Answer (score 1):

jquery-ui.css apply its own styles to .tabs() if you want to use your own style .. remove this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

or you can go to jquery-ui.css and make it blank

Comment: i did that 5 times already, it does not solve it. if i reverse it all the tabs go away! :(

Comment: you can go to jquery-ui.css and make it blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like CSS Viewer in FireFox or it's own developer inspector (right click, inspect element) option to learn what styles are affecting each element and in which style sheet they reside.

You can then override any property from the default style sheet, in your own style sheet by including it (the link to the stylesheet) after the default js  plugin stylesheet and using the !important statement in the involved properties, for example:

```
.elementClass {
border: 1px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your css after `jquery-ui.css`. Also in your css you have to override all the properties set by `jquery-ui.css`. For example, css loaded to `ul li` by `jquery-ui.css` are -

```
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-image: url(http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png);
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
border-bottom-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 59.375px;
line-height: 22.8800010681152px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: -1px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 3.51999998092651px;
margin-top: 1px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
top: 0px;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 194.53125px;
```

So, you have to override all of them.

I also noticed that you didn't set the id `navlist` in your `ul`. So your ul was not getting the css you wrote. I have modified you snippet a bit. It's not exactly ok, but it does show the effect of your css.

```js
$(function() {

      $("#tabs").tabs();

    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #00BFFF;
      }
      div#header {
        width: auto;
        height: 75px;
        background-image: url('banner.gif');
      }
      h1 {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.8em;
      }
      h3 {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1em;
      }
      div#wrapper {
        width: 1200px;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      h1.head,
      h3.subhead {
        font-family: georgia, serif;
        margin-left;
        20px;
      }
      h1.head {
        font-size;
        2.25em;
        padding-top: 15px;
      }
      h3.subhead {
        margin-top: -20px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
      }
      ul#navlist li {
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-right: 30px;
      }
      ul#navlist {
        background-color: #ADFF2F;
        margin-top: .99px;
        margin-bottom: 1.99px;
      }
      ul#navlist a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }
      ul#navlist a:hover {
        color: red;
      }
      div#leftcol {
        float: left;
        width: 180px;
        margin-left: 2px;
      }
      div#maincol {
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      div#maincol h5 {
        font-size: 85%;
        line-height: 1.25em;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 1px;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      }
      div#rightcol {
        width: 180px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 20epx;
      }
      div#footer {
        background-color: #ADFF2F;
        height: 15px;
        clear: both;
      }
      #home div.smfeature {
        width: 180px;
        height: auto;
        border: thin solid red;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      #home div.smfeature h4 {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 75%;
        color: brown;
        background: #48D1CC;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        padding: .5em;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
      }
      div#searchbox2 {
        background-color: #7B68EE;
        text-align: center;
      }
      div#links {
        width: 150px;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      p a:hover {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <div id="tabs">
      <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="#home">Homepage</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="animals.html">Animals</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="Algae.html">Plants</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="FAQS.html">F.A.Qs</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <div id="home">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <!-- header -->
          <div id="header">
            <h1 class="head"> Underwater World </h1>
            <h3 class="subhead">
     A New World!
     </h3>
          </div>


          <!-- left column -->
          <div id="leftcol">

            <div class="smfeature">
              <h4> Who we are. </h4>

            </div>

            <div class="smfeature">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround will be increasing the CSS-specifities. For example I've updated every ul tab properties into 'html body #tabs > ul[role=tablist]' and it will now respect your new rules.

```js
    $(function() {

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    });
```

```css
body { background-color:#00BFFF;}
  
    html body div#header { width:auto;
   height:75px;
   background-image:url('banner.gif');
    } 
    html body h1{ color:white;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:1.8em;
   
   }
    html body h3{ color:white;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:1em;
   
   }
  
    html body div#wrapper{width:1200px;
   background-color:#fff;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   
   
   } 
    
    html body h1.head,html body h3.subhead{font-family:georgia,serif;
     margin-left;20px;}
      
    
       
    html body h1.head{font-size;2.25em;
  padding-top:15px;
  
    }
    html body h3.subhead{ margin-top:-20px;
   letter-spacing:1px;
    }
    html body #tabs > ul[role=tablist] li{ display:inline;
   list-style-type:none;
   padding-right:30px;}
    html body #tabs > ul[role=tablist]{   
   background-color:#ADFF2F;
   margin-top:.99px;
   margin-bottom:1.99px;
   }
    html body #tabs > ul[role=tablist] a{   
   text-decoration:none;
   font-size:1.5em;
   }  
     html body #tabs > ul[role=tablist] a:hover{ color:red;  
     
   } 
 
    html body div#leftcol{ float:left;
   width:180px;
   margin-left:2px;}


    html body div#maincol{float:left;
     width:500px;
   margin-left:15px;
   margin-right:15px;
   text-align:center;
   }
    html body div#maincol h5{font-size:85%;
   line-height:1.25em;
   text-align:center;
   margin-right:1px;
   font-family:arial, sans-serif;
   }
   
    html body div#rightcol{ width:180px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20epx;
    
    }
    html body div#footer{ background-color:#ADFF2F;
     height:15px;
     clear:both;}
    html body #home div.smfeature{width:180px;
   height:auto;
   border:thin solid red;
   margin-bottom:10px;}
    html body #home div.smfeature h4 { font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:75%;
    color:brown;
    background:#48D1CC;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    padding:.5em;
    
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    }
    html body div#searchbox2 { background-color:#7B68EE;
     text-align:center;
     }
    html body div#links { width:150px;
   height:auto;
   text-align:center;
   }
    html body a { text-decoration: none;
 }    
    html body p a:hover{ color:red;}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Homepage</a></li>

    <li><a href="animals.html">Animals</a></li>

    <li><a href="Algae.html">Plants</a></li>

    <li><a href="FAQS.html">F.A.Qs</a></li>
 
 <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="home">
 <div id="wrapper">
 <!-- header -->
 <div id="header">
 <h1 class="head"> Underwater World </h1>
 <h3 class="subhead">
 A New World!
 </h3>
 </div>
 
  
 <!-- left column -->
 <div id="leftcol" >
 
 <div class="smfeature">
 <h4> Who we are. </h4>
 
 </div>
 
 <div class="smfeature">
```